# How can i retrieve all directories and sub directories in OneDrive using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have OneDrive with a number of folders and sub folders .
So I have a root directory with folders as follows
.Main
.Folder1
.Folder1a
.Folder1b
.Folder1b1
.UserDetails
.TextFile.txt

So there are 3 parent folders Main, Folder1 and UserDetails and Folder1 has sub folders Folder1a and Folder1b and Folder1b has sub folder Folder1b1.

I have made a request to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
and try to traverse the result to retrieve the sub directories.
So in the response the list of the folders and the folders inside the folders .

Is there one call i can make that can give me back this data in a Json result set ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understand of your question the desired behavior is for the response to return an object representation of your OneDrive contents.

MSGraph doesn't yet support this functionality, you would have to retrieve sub-folders per folder.
Based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children),  you can use the **drive-id** to make the following request to list the children:

**GET** [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/root/children)

Or if you want to list the items in a sub-folder:

**GET** [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/children)

To list the children based on the Path:

**GET** [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root:/%7Bpath-relative-to-root%7D:/children)

The other way you can go about this, is to write a recursive function on the client side to fetch your oneDrive JSON object.